# jquery and svg animation is incredibly choppy in firefox and safari

Tags: jquery, performance, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a designer, and I've been hacking together a portfolio site as best I can, but things are starting to break and I've reached the limit of my google abilities. 
 you can view the site [here](http://www.dev.jcohendesign.com/).

I have templated content that is loaded dynamically into tabs that are hidden and shown with a combination of the native bootstrap tab classes and js. I essentially just want the links to show the appropriate content and then animate a page scroll down to the gallery area.

This is basically what happens in Chrome, but in Safari it kind of jumps around the screen and doesn't really animate. Same in Firefox. I believe this behavior is also causing the arrow navigation on the slide to drop to the bottom of the slide. You can see what's going on by clicking one of the four links (branding, typography, interactive, illustration), the home or all work link in the gallery section, or the thumbnails at the bottom.

There are other related performance things, like the frame rate on the collapse animation for the contact link, and the amount of time it takes for the background image swap to happen on hover.

Here's the script for activating the relevant work sections..

```
<script>
    $('#work-link a, #branding a, #interactive a, #typography a, #illustration a').click(function (event) {
        $(this).tab('show');
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top }, 800);
        event.preventDefault;
    })
</script>
<script>
    $('.thumb-tile a').click(function (event){
    $('.swatch-tab').removeClass("active");
    $('#all-work').addClass("active");
    $(this).tab('show');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top }, 800);
        event.preventDefault();
    })
</script>
```

let me know if there are is other code I should post.

Thanks

Comment: You should create a small simple self-contained example showing just the issue. There's a lot going on on your website and it's much easier if we don't have to dig through lots of unnecessary stuff.

Comment: I'm totally sympathetic to what you are saying, but I wouldn't know what to separate out or how.